# How to obtain database info and statistics using mgconsole?

Tags: memgraphdb

When I use [Memgraph Lab](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph-lab) I can see the database statistics at the top of the window.
How can I obtain info such as Memgrph version, number of nodes, relationships, etc. when I'm using `mgconsole`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the information on Memgraph version that is being used use the `SHOW VERSION;` query.

To get the information about the storage of the current instance use `SHOW STORAGE INFO;`. This query will give you the following info:

- `vertex_count` - Number of vertices stored
- `edge_count` - Number of edges stored
- `average_degree` - Average number of relationships of a single node
- `memory_usage` - Amount of RAM used reported by the OS (in bytes)
- `disk_usage` - Amount of disk space used by the data directory (in bytes)
- `memory_allocated` - Amount of bytes allocated by the instance
- `allocation_limit` - Current allocation limit in bytes set for this instance